# How to get the previous char of a given char in java?

Tags: java

the user will enter a char and I have to implement the previous char then the given char then the previous char again for example:
input: B
output: ABA
so how to get the previous char?

Comment: Learn about the asciitable

Comment: Given your current definition it is unclear what the "previous char" of `A` would be

Comment: In Java `char` is *numeric* type representing *index* of character in Unicode Table. So if you have `char ch = 'B';` you can cast it to `int` to see index of `A` via `int index = (int)ch;`. Also we can use mathematical operators on `char` like `+` `-` for instance `'A'+1`. BUT result of such calculation will be of type `int` not `char`, so you may need to cast that result back to `char` if you want to know what symbol is after it like `char afterB = (char)('B'+1);`.

Comment: Try executing `System.out.println((char)('B' - 1));`